# How do I 'follow' a property changing event up the inheritance ladder

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance, user-controls

I have a user control which will form the base for other composite user controls which I intend to build upon it.  Within that base control I have a property defined below with an on change event related to it.

```
Private _themeToUse As String
Public Property ThemeToUse As String
    Get
        Return _themeToUse
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _themeToUse = value
        RaiseEvent ThemeToUseOnChange(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Set
End Property

Public Event ThemeToUseOnChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)


Private Sub ThemeChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.ThemeToUseOnChange
    ThemeController.Theme = ThemeToUse
End Sub
```

What I am trying to figure out is how my new user controls that use this base control as the control from which they themselves inherit can utilise the on change event.

I have tried adding the following to my new control that is inheriting the base control after intellisense suggested using 'Shadows' but it does not appear to be getting fired.

```
Shadows Event ThemeToUseOnChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)


Private Sub ThemeChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.ThemeToUseOnChange
    C1ThemeController1.Theme = ThemeToUse
End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me how I ought to be doing this sort of thing properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this as your base class:

```
Public Class First

    Public Event ThemeToUseChanged As EventHandler
    Public Event ThemeToUseChanging As EventHandler

    Public Property ThemeToUse() As String
        Get
            Return Me.m_themeToUse
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If (value <> Me.m_themeToUse) Then
                Me.OnThemeToUseChanging(EventArgs.Empty)
                Me.m_themeToUse = value
                Me.OnThemeToUseChanged(EventArgs.Empty)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overridable Sub OnThemeToUseChanged(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If (Not Me.ThemeToUseChangedEvent Is Nothing) Then
            Me.ThemeToUseChangedEvent.Invoke(Me, e)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnThemeToUseChanging(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If (Not Me.ThemeToUseChangingEvent Is Nothing) Then
            Me.ThemeToUseChangingEvent.Invoke(Me, e)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private m_themeToUse As String

End Class
```

And this class inherits everything from `First` class:

```
Public Class Second
    Inherits First

End Class
```

Now you can add handles to both the `ThemeToUseChanged` event and the `ThemeToUseChanging` event of each object:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Test:
        Me._first.ThemeToUse = New Guid().ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'Test:
        Me._second.ThemeToUse = New Guid().ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThemeToUseChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _first.ThemeToUseChanged, _second.ThemeToUseChanged
        If (sender Is Me._first) Then
            'ThemeToUseChanged changed of type `First`
        ElseIf (sender Is Me._second) Then
            'ThemeToUseChanged changed of type `Second`
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThemeToUseChanging(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _first.ThemeToUseChanging, _second.ThemeToUseChanging
        If (sender Is Me._first) Then
            'ThemeToUseChanging changed of type `First`
        ElseIf (sender Is Me._second) Then
            'ThemeToUseChanging changed of type `Second`
        End If
    End Sub

    Private WithEvents _first As New First
    Private WithEvents _second As New Second

End Class
```

And if you consider a `Third` class inherits `Second`:

```
Public Class Third
    Inherits Second

End Class
```

This is how you can loop through the inheritance chain:

```
Dim obj As First = New Third()
Dim t As Type = obj.GetType()

Do
    MsgBox(t.FullName)
    t = t.BaseType
Loop Until (t.BaseType Is Nothing)
```

Comment: Thank you Bjorn that's a very nice and elegant solution.

Comment: @DomSinclair I'm glad it helped! FYI: I've added some more info.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you ought to make the property **value** part of the event, just as mouse click events include click and mouse info:

```
Class ThemeChangedEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Proptery OldTheme As String
    Public Proptery NewTheme As String

    Sub New(oldT As String, newT AS String)
        OldTheme = oldT
        NewTheme = newT
    End Sub
 End CLass

 Public Event ThemeChanged(Sender as Object, e As ThemeChangedEventArgs)
```

Then:

```
Property Theme As String
 ...
 Set(value as string)

    RaiseEvent ThemeChanged(Me, New ThemeChangedEventArgs(_Theme, value))
    _Theme = Value
 End Set
```

The event would be usually used to inform the subscriber - like a form - that the theme changed.  They can also be used to bubble up information from child classes, but this more or less requires the parent to define the event and know about the property in the first place. In which case:

```
 Property Theme As String
 ...
 Set(value as string)
    MyBase.Theme = value

 End Set
```

This would tell a parent class the same thing with less code, assuming the property is defined upstream and not in this class.

Children using events for property changes is something more like this:

```
Class Parent
   ...
   Protected Friend MustOverride Property Theme() As String

   Public Event ThemeChanged ...
```

Any class which inherits from Parent is required to define Theme, so it knows about it, just not the details.  The subscriber event is also defined at the Parent level which allows the event to be fired by whichever class is actually implementing it.

Where events come in handy on these is internal processes.  Something happens deep down, so a class raises a `FooChange event`, the parent respond in `OnFooChange`, does something like calculate the impact of the change, then maybe raises a user event (for a form) like `FooBarChange`.  The Child knows about Foo, but the Parent handles Bar, so you can use an internal event to notify the Parent.